Facebook Graph API Responses Inconsistent: Empty Results on VPS, Successful on Local IP
I'm encountering an inconsistency with accessing the Facebook Graph API. When making requests from my local IP address, I receive the expected JSON responses containing product data. However, attempts from my VPS IP address result in empty responses with no data returned. Here are the responses:
Local IP Response:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "*****",
      "name": "4LAE 040 110 S04  (4*11*45L)",
      "retailer_id": "ACBrg"
    },
    // More product data...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "eyJvZAmZAzZAXQiOjB9",
      "after": "eyJvZAmZAzZAXQiOjI0fQZDZD"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/***************/products?access_token=...&pretty=1&limit=25&after=eyJvZAmZAzZAXQiOjI0fQZDZD",
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/***************/products?access_token=...&pretty=1&limit=25&before=eyJvZAmZAzZAXQiOjB9"
  }
}

VPS Response
{
  "data": []
}

Despite using the same URL (https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/***************/products) and access token, the response from the VPS does not contain any product data. I have ensured that the URL, access token, and server configurations are correct. Any insights on why the VPS responses differ from those of my local IP and how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated."
